C++ sort() function function stops with an error message
I received an error while trying to run the following code, why is this happening? Do the sort function have any additional requirements for the comparison function
run the code

#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

bool cmp(int i,int j){
    return i<=j;
}
int main(){
    int n=42;
    int arr[]={36,0,21,52,13,24,47,88,83,19,36,50,85,37,6,85,43,18,11,100,78,43,0,43,18,99,38,62,56,82,16,81,22,75,33,80,34,57,30,5,58,91};
    sort(arr,arr+n,cmp);
    return 0;
}


Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library:
Expression: invalid comparator

The predicate says whether i is ordered before j. It must be a strict weak ordering which, among other things, means that an object cannot be ordered before itself. (I.e. cmp(x,x) must be false for all x.) See std::sort.

So just use < instead of <=.

@molbdnilo
Can it be understood that the sort function requires the sorted result to be unique? For example, if the cmp function returns true for input (A, B), then it must return false for (B, A), even if A and B are numerically equal but not equal at the address where the data is stored

@gbdj See the Compare requirements. ("Equal" or "not equal" does not come into play here, the slightly weaker relation equivalence is what matters. That said, "A and B are numerically equal but not equal at the address where the data is stored" makes no sense.)

Values do not need to be unique. If cmp(A,B) and cmp(B,A) are false then in the sorted result B can be before or after A. To keep initial A and B relative positions, there is std::stable_sort().

@gbdj Do you know internally how Visual C++ determines that the comparitor is invalid?  It is a two-step test.  Assume that items A and B are equal.  The sort function gives your comparitor A and B, and since you have <=, you return true.  Then the sort function gives you B and then A.  Again you return true.  So which item goes before the other?  You first said that A goes before B, and then you said that B goes before A.  That is an ambiguity, and that is exactly how the std::sort implementation (at least in debug mode) works.
